# Node.JS + mySQL -> How to do the ajax call and access the data on server.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, node.js

So this is my server.js file, where the db is being connected to :

```
var app = require('express')();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createConnection({

    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'user_data',
    port: 3306
});
db.connect();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/start.html");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

So I want to make something like a registration form, where you input your username and password. Then, after you click the submit button, the username and password are supposed to go straight to the mySQL database. So apparently, I need an ajax call which sends the data to that server, but I don't know how to access it on the server.js.

```
$("button#submit").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
           'url': 'http://localhost:3000',
           'type': 'post',
           'data': {
                'username': $("#usr").val(),
                'password': $("#pwd").val()
           },
           'success': function (data) {
                alert('Data: ' + data);
           }
        });
  })
```

After I get that data on the server.js, I will obviously want to make a query (to insert the values) but how do I get the data?

Comment: mhm? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it for one of my projects:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Contact Form</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="contact">
    <h1>Send an email</h1>
    <form action="/myaction" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />

            <label for="location">Location:</label>
            <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Enter your location" />

            <input type="submit" value="Send message" />

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when user clicks submit /myaction url will hit.

```
db.connect(function(err,connection){
    app.post('/myaction',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);

     var employee={name:req.body.name,location:req.body.location}

    db.query('INSERT into employees SET ?',employee,function(err,res){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
        else{
        console.log(res);

    }


        })
   res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
})
})
```

Make sure to include these in your server.js

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app=express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

So you can see i have defined app.post and I am hitting my url. Then we simply write a sql query to store data.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I will try this out

Comment: Well, req.body.name is undefined

Comment: or to be more specific, req.body is

Comment: req.body is the data you are sending to server, so for name req.body.name.

Comment: for you it will be req.body.username. Is req.body showing up or req.body is also undefined.?

Comment: also check if in your database is there a NULL entry.??

Comment: req.body is undefined

Comment: is there any NULL entry in your database??

Comment: Also make sure to include bodyparser:                                                              app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); and  app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: Well why not? If something is not set for a certain user, it will be a null entry. Don't see why this is a problem. Also, where to put this?

Comment: put this in your server.js file. The file through your server is started. Just verify.

Comment: Something like, var bodyParser = require('body-parser') ? But that module is undefined and npm didnt work for the installation

Comment: Windows_NT 6.1.7601

Comment: Do you have a proxy between you and the internet? The error you're getting is an SSL error that indicates that something is interfering with the npm CLI's ability to talk to its registry securely.

Comment: check by turning off your firewall or antivirus

Comment: Cant I just do it with ajax call?

Comment: See your request data will come part of body-parser. So you need it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this problem will be solved after this.