# Use AJAX to make a database query on Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax

I'm using Node.js as server with Mysql as database for storing logged in usernames. Can I use AJAX to make a sql database query and return the list of usernames?

To be specific I want to use XMLHttp request and get the results without reloading the page.

Please excuse me if the question doesn't make sense. I'm from Mechanical Engineering background.

Comment: Sure, ajax is independent of what backend technology you want to use. However you mention you have a node.js server, why do you need .asp files ?

Comment: I've fast search this site. Might to be helpful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971941/node-js-mysql-how-to-do-the-ajax-call-and-access-the-data-on-server-js

Comment: go through this - https://gistpages.com/posts/expressjs_and_mysql_sample_application_and_tutorial

Comment: @SujalMandal Thank you so much. I have actually finished that part, It reloads the page and then gives the results. To be more specific I wanted to use XMLHttp() request and stay on same page.

Comment: @VasylMoskalov Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Setup js file to server express,
express will handle routes
route for CRUD

express will also open connection with DB using ORM like Sequelize
and whenever a CRUD operation occurs from the front end -> Node back end
then your express app will run the code in the appropriate route
the route will have the logic for CRUD on the DB queries.

this is a long process to explain requires knowledge of how to request the backend for information via url -> backend listerers of a sort lol

that's the gist.

front end will send ajax -> to backend and backend will listen to that route or something like that.

@Sujal Mandal he found a good reference go with his answer, i just skimmed it but looks right.